# Using another proxy every php request (curl / file_get_contents)

Tags: php, curl, proxy, file-get-contents

Trying to get contents of a url, but to avoid getting blocked i want to use a proxy every request.
But both ways do not seem to work...

EDIT:

Now i tried this, but my server log keeps logging my real IP.

```
$page = file_get_contents("https://free-proxy-list.net/");
preg_match_all("/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}<\/td><td>[0-9]{1,5}/", $page, $matches);

$randomproxy = $matches[0][array_rand($matches[0])];
$randomproxy = "tcp://".str_replace("</td><td>", ":", $randomproxy);
echo $randomproxy;

// configure default context to use proxy


$opts = array(
    'tcp' => array(
        'proxy' => $randomproxy
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$sFile = file_get_contents("https://www.website.tld/inner.html", False, $context);
var_dump($sFile);
```

Comment: What you mean by "not seem to work"? Please provide *specific* error messages, incorrect behavior descriptions, or log file outputs.

Comment: How you figure out "both way didn't work"? Can you create simple webserver and check which IP address is coming

Comment: my script is automatically being blocked after a while, i get no access anymore. Also pinging does not work anymore. So i figure the proxy is not changing. I will try fetching from my own server, good idea!

Comment: I edited my code sample, still my server log is returning my real ip in stead of the proxy